# XPath selecting specific child element

Tags: xpath

I've some problem with Xpath syntax with html. I want to select an item which is into a div.

I have a Div define by an id : "popin".

In this div, I have a span with his id is "id_yes".

I can get the div with `//DIV[contains(@id ,'popin')]`  but I failed to get the span element.

Have you a solution ?

Comment: You should post your XML as code, not prose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ID, you can use:
`//span[@id="id_yes"]`

If you want to be more specific, `//div[@id="popin"]/span[@id="id_yes"]`

That, assuming your IDs are unique.

Comment: the id of the span is not unique, this is why I want to specify in which div the span is located.

Comment: Then you can use that second option, because it specifies the div with # popin and then finds the span inside that div.